# Get only element of a collection view with Guava, without exception when there are multiple elements

Tags: java, guava

I want to have two functions. The first will, given a Collection, return the elements that satisfy a predicate. The predicate can be quite expensive, and the result not be consumed entirely, so I figured the best course of action was to return a view. And therefore, once implemented, my method is just something that encapsulates Guava's Collections2.filter:

```
Collection<MyElement> getInterestingElements(Collection<MyElement> allElements) {
    return Collections2.filter(allElements, new Predicate<MyElement>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(MyElement element) {
            return element.isInteresting();  // call expensive function
        }
    });
}
```

(class names have been changed to protect the innocent)

My second function will call the first one and returns:

- null if the collection contains zero or more than one element.
- the only element of the collection if the collection contains only one element.

That is, this function will return the content of the collection if and only if this collection is a singleton.

A naive implementation would be:

```
MyElement getElementIfOnlyInterestingOne(Collection<MyElement> allElements) {
    Collection<MyElement> interestingElements = getInterestingElements(allElements);

    if (interestingElements.size() != 1){
        return null;
    }

    return Iterables.first(interestingElements, null);
}
```

But the call to `size()` will (I think) evaluate the predicate for all the elements of the underlying collection, and that's unacceptable when I'm just interested in the first element.

I could use Iterables.getOnlyElement() but this throw an exception if the collection is not a singleton, which should happen often, and I think it's a bad practice to rely on an exception to do that.

So I have to manually iterate, store in a variable the first element, and return null if there is a second element.

My question is: this is fine but am I not reinventing the wheel? There is so much magic in Guava that this problem must be solved by a `isSingleton` or `getSingleElementOrNull` somewhere :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the method must be implemented as described where a filtered collection with anything other than one element must return `null`, the best I can come up with is a solution you've already suggested.

```
Collection<MyElement> interestingElements = getInterestingElements(allElements);
Iterator<MyElement> iterator = interestingElements.iterator();
if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
    return null;
}
MyElement first = iterator.next();
if (iterator.hasNext()) { // More than one element
    return null;
} else {
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The "Guava way" would be to use [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html)'s [`firstMatch`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#firstMatch-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) method, which returns [`Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) instance. In your case:

```
MyElement interestingOrNull = FluentIterable.from(allElements)
    .firstMatch(new Predicate<MyElement>() {
      @Override
      public boolean apply(MyElement element) {
        return element.isInteresting();
      }
    })
    .orNull();
```

*(Even more "Guava way" would be not using `null` after all...)*

Comment: Nice clean way. Could be improved as mentioned, fromMatch returns an Optional which you can check is present before doing anything with the result.. you could then return an Optional.absent() in an or() to ensure no null pointers.

Comment: Doesn't satisfy requirement of returning a value if and only if there is exactly one interesting value.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the FluentIterable suggestion above doesn't deal with the size>2 => null portion of the problem. Personally, I'd go with the Iterables.getOnlyValue approach. It's slightly messy, but it simplifies the code a great deal, and the intent is clear.